# How to delete the data in Character device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written some data into my character device in `/dev/my_char`.
What should I do to delete the data without removing the device from the kernel ? .

The method which I follow to delete the contents is to 
1) rm `/dev/my_char` and 
2) rmmod My_Char.

But by using this method, I have to insert the module again into the kernel and create the device in dev folder which is a lengthy process.

Using only `rm /dev/my_char` doesn't delete its contents.

I would like to know if there is any other method other than this.

Comment: `0 > /dev/my_char`: this writes `0` in the file, `> /dev/my_char` should clear it.

Comment: @brokenfoot 0>/dev/my_char doesn't work as there is an error bash: 0: command not found where as giving only > /dev/my_char is not clearing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to delete the data in the device by just removing the module from the kernel and then loading the module again to the kernel.ie "rmmod My_Char" and again "insmod My_Char".By this method we need not create the device again in the /dev/my_char as it will be automatically loaded with no data.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement an ioctl to reset the input buffer.

1. Add an ioctl handler to the driver.
2. Add the entry point to the file_operations structure.  `.unlocked_ioctl =`(your function name)
3. For the case of the correct ioctl command, reset the buffer pointer(s), clear the count, or whatever is needed to make the device look empty.

Or you could write a script to remove the driver and reload it.  Here is what I use (I call it `reload`):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d /device/my_device ]; then
    sudo rmmod my_device.ko
fi

VERBOSE=0
MESSAGES=0
VENDOR=
DEVICEID=

while (( $# > 0 ))
do
    arg="$1"
    shift

    case $arg in
    v=* | ve=* | ver=* | verb=* | verbo=* | verbos=* | verbose=*)
        VERBOSE=${arg#*=}
        ;;

    v | ve | ver | verb | verbo | verbos | verbose)
        VERBOSE=1
        ;;

    t  | tt | tty)
        MESSAGES=1
        ;;

    ven=* | vend=* | vendo=* | vendor=*)
        VENDOR="opt_vendor_id=${arg#*=}"
        ;;

    ven | vend | vendo | vendor)
        VENDOR="opt_vendor_id=$1"
        shift
        ;;

    d=* | de=* | dev=* | devi=* | devic=* | device=*)
        DEVICEID="opt_device_id=${arg#*=}"
        ;;

    d | de | dev | devi | devic | device)
        DEVICEID="opt_device_id=$1"
        shift
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Invalid option '$arg':"
        echo "Options are 'verbose', 'tty', 'vendor='<vendor number>, and 'deviceid='<device id>"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "insmod my_device.ko opt_verbose=$VERBOSE opt_tty_msgs=$MESSAGES $VENDOR $DEVICEID"
sudo insmod my_device.ko opt_verbose=$VERBOSE opt_tty_msgs=$MESSAGES $VENDOR $DEVICEID
```

This has a lot of extra complexity to handle parameters which are passed to the module when it is loaded.  If you don't have any module parameters, the above can be simplified to:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d /device/my_device ]; then
    sudo rmmod my_device.ko
fi

sudo insmod my_device.ko
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with your character device as if it is a generic file

```sh
cat /dev/null > /dev/my_char
```

Comment: V.Alexeev The command mentioned is not clearing the data in /dev/mychar.

Comment: You should look in your device driver code then. It is nothing to do with the shell

Comment: V.ALexeev I think there is nothing to do with the driver code as the device is created in command window using mknod /dev/my_char c 251 0.Therefore I should also be able to delete the contents in it.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Unlike block device  character device usually has no capability of random access. For the most part, reading and writing data to a character device is not buffered. So you can't delete data from /dev/my_char. You can only read or write. 

Typical examples of character devices are: tape drive, modem, or TTY terminal. The data which is sent ... is sent. There is no way to delete it

Comment: Its possible to delete the data in the device by just removing the module from the kernel and then loading the module again to the kernel.ie "rmmod My_Char" and again "insmod ./My_Char.ko".By this method we need not create the device again in the /dev/my_char as it will be automatically loaded with empty data in it.